# Docker container cannot find the main class of api-rest in jar when launch

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, jar

I build a jar of my spring-boot api with gradle but after launch the docker container it stop itself and logs say "Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.exampleController"

This is for a Docker project

I insert this code in my build.gradle:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.test.exampleController'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

I'm not sure if I need some anotation in the class or if the problem is because I have 3 controllers

I expect to run a docker container with tha spring-boot api and test it whit other app like postman for example

Comment: Don't write your own task. The gradle spring boot task does all that. So ditch your `fatJar` task and just use the spring boot task (which will be executed by default if you simply add the plugin).

Comment: I tried generate the jar file with the task of gradle but didn't generate nothing. I followed this steps:
gradle tab --> projectName --> Tasks --> build --> jar
I think that need a instruccion in my build.gradle that is missing, can you giveme a example? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ok finally I found the code that was misssing in my gradle:
```
jar {
 baseName = 'example-api'
 version =  '0.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Applying the spring boot plugin and just do `gradle build` should all you need. It will take the defaults (name and group) to generate the artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the error, I was trying built the jar with the incorrect launcher. In gradle tabs I can find tasks, inside in build appear 'jar' between others and that was my error, I was thinking "If I want a jar this is my task" but not, I wanted a springboot's jar and that it implies that I need that jar has main-class and launcher. To do this exist another option in my task, "bootjar". That build a manifest file with main-class defined and start-class. Adjunt image

[image]